# How to set position in the screen?

Tags: java, android

I have writing code to create game Tower of Hanoi.

I use linear layout and divide into 3 part. I can set the action down, move, up.

How to set when I touch to screen will select imageview 1 is to the top in part 1 ( number 1 in this photo). then I move to it in part 2 and stop touch. this view will drop down such as my description in this photo.

How to set imageviews stacked up.
Thanks for reading my question.

[My Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxIod.png)
My code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imgdiamot;
int mode =0;
int DRAG =1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Movedisk();
}
private void Movedisk(){
    imgdiamot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdiamot);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,190);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 160;
    layoutParams.topMargin = 450;
    imgdiamot.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    imgdiamot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
        float dx=0,dy=0,x=0,y=0;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
            switch (event.getAction()& MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                    dx = event.getRawX() - params.leftMargin;
                    dy = event.getRawY() -params.topMargin;
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(mode==DRAG){
                        x = event.getRawX();
                        y = event.getRawY();

                        params.leftMargin = (int) (x -dx);
                        params.topMargin = (int) (y-dy);
                        params.rightMargin=0;
                        params.bottomMargin =0;
                        params.rightMargin = params.leftMargin + (10*params.width);
                        params.bottomMargin=params.topMargin + (10*params.height);
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

                    }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried

Comment: I posted the code in the answer below. i can't the post in there because it very long. @MacLeanSochor

Comment: You _can_ post your code in your question, and it is encouraged that you do so with an edit

Comment: i posted my code.@MacLeanSochor